# Console spam when opening editor: Assertion failed on expression: 'txn.Exists(guid)'

Tags: unity

I have just opened up a new project in Unity 2019.3.04b - and in the console I got an error message repeating a lot of times:

[image: error image]

In addition, when unfocus and focus Unity, it spits out one more pair of errors (the same errors like in this image).

Anyone knows what it is and how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like it's a bug with Unity: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ugui-assertions-spam-the-console-when-minimizing-the-editor-window . Looks like there is a workaround in the comments.

Comment: Great! thanks a lot!

Comment: If you find that the workaround proposed there fixes it for you, you could write an answer here to help future users.

Comment: I have no idea how, but the problem just fixed itself somehow (I literally did nothing)!

Comment: ✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨